Trying to plot a ResidualsPlot (Yellowbrick) ValueError: x and y must be the same size
I attempted to plot a ResidualsPlot of my XGBoostRF model, but initially encountered the following error:
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 13.0 GiB for an array with shape (58987, 58987) and data type float32
This error seems illogical because I have two arrays, one with dimensions (58987, 5) and the other (58987, 1).
Subsequently, I attempted to create a random array solely for testing purposes. I generated two arrays of size (100,1), executed the model, and then attempted to plot the residuals again. However, a new error emerged:
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBRFRegressor

xaleatorio = np.random.rand(100,1)
yaleatorio = np.random.rand(100, 1)

y = yaleatorio
X = xaleatorio
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split,cross_val_score

#SPLITANDO
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size= 0.20, random_state=42)

from yellowbrick.regressor import ResidualsPlot, PredictionError
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

bst = RandomForestRegressor()
bst.fit(X_train,y_train)

visualizer = PredictionError(bst)

visualizer.fit(X_train, y_train) 
visualizer.score(X_test,y_test)
visualizer.show()

visualizer = ResidualsPlot(bst)

visualizer.fit(X_train, y_train) 
visualizer.score(X_test,y_test)
visualizer.show()   


